# Local unit test while using Call<T> object in Retrofit

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I have following unitTest :

```
@Test
    fun loadMovieTrailer() {
        val video = Video("id", "name", "site",
                "videoId", 20, "type")

        val observableResponse =
                Observable.just(MovieApi.VideoWrapper(Lists.newArrayList(video)))
        `when`(movieApi.trailers(anyString())).thenReturn(observableResponse)


        with(viewModel) {
            assertFalse(isTrailersVisible.get())

            showTrailers(movie)

            assertTrue(isTrailersVisible.get())
            assertFalse(trailers.isEmpty())
            assertTrue(trailers.size == 1)
        }
    }
```

And this is `movieApi.trailers` retrofit api method :

```
@GET("3/movie/{movieId}/videos")
    fun trailers(@Path("movieId") movieId: String): Observable<VideoWrapper>
```

I have another method in MovieApi which I want to write a test for :

```
@GET("3/discover/movie?language=en&sort_by=popularity.desc")
    fun popularMovies(@Query("page") page: Int): Call<MovieWrapper>
```

As you see it returns `Call<T>` object instead of `Observable`. How can I have a replacement for following part in test method ?

```
Observable.just(MovieApi.VideoWrapper(Lists.newArrayList(video)))
            `when`(movieApi.trailers(anyString())).thenReturn(observableResponse)
```

Full sample code can be found at : https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/TMDb-Paging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`retrofit-mock`](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-mock) for this.

```
val mockCall = Calls.response(Response.success(myTestData))
`when`(api.myFunction()).thenReturn(mockCall)
```

Comment: Thanks @Brucelet, I faced with another problem that I asked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54061083/kotlinnullpointerexception-in-unittest